# Vector with function as elements

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, integral

I'm try to compute this integral in R numerically :

[image]

where

[image]

cm and cf are function that I already know and gamma is a parameter also known.

What I wanted to do is to compute the integral for a=18,19,20,...,65 
Hence basically, I would like to construct a vector of size 48 in which the first element is pi(18), the second pi(19),untill pi(65).

Is it possible to do it in R ?

I have only tried to compute the integrand inside lambda (just to try if it works) in the following way

```
integrand <- vector(mode="numeric") 
for (i in 1:48){
 integrand[i] <- function(a.f){exp(0.83-0.071*a.f)*
 exp(-0.970774-0.077159*a.f)*
 (1/sqrt(((-0.67+0.133*a.f)^{2})*pi))*exp(-(1/(-0.67+0.133*a.f)^{2})*(i-a.f- 2)^{2})}
}
```

But I obtain the error:

> "incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix"

Therefore I have no clue on how solving my initial integral.

Comment: Without going into the math, there are some problems in your code : 1) your assigning a function to a vector, so you're creating a vector of functions, 2) the for loop is a bad idea in R, you should look at `sapply`/`lapply` to apply a function to a vector or a list, or depending on what you want directly use vectorised computation

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you are almost there. R is so powerful because it is vectorized, which we can use to get the result:

```
a.f <- 1:48

integrand <- exp(0.83-0.071*a.f)*
  exp(-0.970774-0.077159*a.f)*
  (1/sqrt(((-0.67+0.133*a.f)^2)*pi))*
  exp(-(1/(-0.67+0.133*a.f)^2)*(i-a.f- 2)^2)
```

Which gives a vector (integrand) of length 48 with the values.

Is that something that you want/need?